# how to stop all quartz schedular job of an entire bean in springs java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Hi i am trying to stop all the jobs related to an entire bean. so can any one help how to resolve this.?

below is my bean.xml

```
  <bean id="schedulerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">      
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
            <ref local="projectedWeeklyRevenueCronTrigger"/>
            <!--<ref local="pdfEfficiencyByWeekProviderProgramCronTrigger"/> -->
            <ref local="actualWeeklyRevenueCronTrigger"/>
            <ref local="notesArchivalCronTrigger"/>
            <ref local="actualRevenueReportCronTriggerAfterInvoicing"/>
            <ref local="actualRevenueReportCronTriggerMidOfMonth"/>
            <ref local="efficienyReportCronTrigger"/>
            <ref local="dailyCensusCronTrigger"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Thanks in advance.
-Satheesh Appu

Answer (score 0):

In the job class implement `org.quartz.InterruptableJob` interface, after that call `org.quartz.Scheduler.interrupt(JobKey)` for stopping or interrupting the job. take a look at [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html)